# how to name a class that generate other classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have several classes that all implementing an interface:

```
  interface ISample
  {
  }

  class A:ISample
  {
  }
  class B:ISample
  {
  }
  class C:ISample
  {
  }
```

and another class that create them based on some situation for example:

```
  class CreateISample
  {
        ISample Create(string situation )
         { 
             switch(situation )
             {
                 case "create A":
                    return new A();
                 case "Create B":
                    return new B();
                 case "Create C":
                    return new C();
              }
         }
   }
```

What is the best name for this class?

Create ISample is not good, as then I have:

```
   CreateISample.Create("Create A");
```

which has two Create as part of name. Also CreateISample may do some other things (for example hold some constant values that relates to all instances, or hold a list of created instances and so on). Then CreateISample is not a good name.

Is there any standard for this? I remember that I read a book about design patterns and they suggested a suitable name for this factory pattern.

Comment: What about naming it SampleFactory and moving question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com or http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'd call it Bob  (tgif :) )

Comment: What about `GenerateISample` ?

Comment: @Sean, no; a method name should start with a verb, but not a class name

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - sorry, I meant the class should be called `GenerateISample`, not the method. `ISampleGenerator` sounds like a better name, but would give the impression it's an interface.

Answer (score 5):

you are describing the factory pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

generally the convention we use is SampleFactory

But don't overthink it. It's really hard to make names like this from samples. for example it is obvious to most people that a square inherrits from shape. so

```
 ShapeFactory.Create("Square");
```

would make a lot of sense. so look at your problem to see what kind of thing ISample really is. If i makes sense from a business/problem side other programmers who understand the problem can figure it out.

Comment: So essentially it is a good idea to use <name>Factory. Should it be a static class or a normal class?